# How can prevent the apache ErrorDocument from passing path infomation?

Tags: apache-2.2, errordocument

I am trying to forward all requests to a particular hostname to a specific URL.

My virtual host entry looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.example.com
    RedirectPermanent / http://another.example.com/path/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works for anyone going to http://test.example.com.  I am trying to add an error handler:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://another.example.com/path/
```

so that any and all requests go to the same server.  The problem is that if I request http://test.example.com/foo then the end result is a request to http://another.example.com/path/foo.  I tried setting the error document to http://another.example.com/path? but it ignored the ? and still redirected to /path/foo

How do I prevent the path from being added to the error URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just need `RedirectMatch permanent ^ http://another.example.com/path/` instead of RedirectPermanent or ErrorDocument.